# Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier

Tags: button, twitter, identifier

Im trying to make a basic applescript that will tell an open application to press upload when a new tweet has been received. The script is giving me the error in the title and highlights the word 'button' when i compile it.
Can anyone give me a heads up on where I've gone wrong?.

repeat

```
tell application "safari"
    set URL of tab 1 of window 1 to "https://twitter.com/i/connect"
    delay 5
    if text of tab 1 of window 1 contains "1 new interaction"
        tell application "Arduino" to activate 
        click button "Upload" of window 1
        delay 1
    end if
end tell
```

end repeat